# How to distinguish between a prop and a method with the same name, in Vue?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I recently switched from React to Vue. In React, i often had a method in a child component, that would look something like this:

```
onClick = (e)=>{
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.props.onClick(val)
  }
```

I see that Vue is very "free", and allows you to treat component methods and props as "the same thing".

Is there some way to distinguish between the two, like with this.props? What is the convention regarding this issue?

Comment: you can use this.$props, but it's generally better to create different names, because as you know, it doesn't distinguish between props, methods, computed or data.

Comment: In your case, instead of pass function via prop, it is better to emit an event and handle it in the parent component.

Comment: First of all a name for a method "onClick" is very very bad. Name of a function should tell you what that function does. But with "onClick" you know it is doing "something" on a click. How useful is that? Which is better `@click="callPropMethod"`or `@click="onClick"` ?

Comment: Adam, you're right, i just gave a very bad example...a better example would be something like "onDeleteUser" or something like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props, data, computed properties and methods end up as properties on Vue instance - members may also include lifecycle hooks when a component is declared as [a class](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component). As with any other class, their names may collide.

In case there are members that are private (`onClick` method) and are parts of public API (`onClick` prop), they can be named differently, e.g. with underscore naming convention that is common in JS OOP:

```
...
props: {
    onClick: Function
},
methods: {
    _onClick() {...}
}
...
```

The use of naming conventions for private properties is suggested by [Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Private-property-names-essential).

In composition API and Vue 3, there is a clear distinction in `setup` because `props` object is available, so it could be done similarly to how the question suggests. There is no difference between props and instance properties in templates so the rest of the answer is still applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of another Vue technique, instead of passing a function, using its event emitter system:

```
// MyComponent:
methods: {
    onClick(e) {
        const val = e.target.value;
        this.emit('click', val);
    }
}
...
<button @click="onClick">Click me</button>


//When you actually use your component

<MyComponent @click="() => { console.log('delegated onClick!'); }"/>
```

Comment: How come this technique is better?

Comment: Because that is the system every other vue component also uses, and the syntax for when you want to listen to the standard components, and making your components match the same interface as the system components makes it predictable for an end user

Comment: I see. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in one of the comments try to avoid using duplicate names for props, methods, etc...

Comment: As mentioned everywhere on Stackoverflow, try to avoid writing comments as answers